# Its possible make a responsive site 100% without mediaqueries or flexbox?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would know if is possible create a site responsive to 100% without flexbox or media queries. I discard the possibility of use position, width, height and px. I've tried using percent %, margin, padding and column-count, and work, but not to 100%. Like you can see, with some resolution like 1440 x 629 the box restrict in height and the text change.
[image]
How to Can I fix it without media queries or flexbox?

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
main {
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3%;
}
main > * {
  color: #fff;
}
section.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1%;
}
section.navigation-bar > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
section.navigation-bar ul li {
  display: inline;
}
section.navigation-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
section.navigation-bar ul li a:hover {
  color: #abc;
}
section.columns-area {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
section.columns-area > aside {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
}
section.footer {
  background-color: #fff;
}
p.footer-text {
  color: #000;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
p.footer-text > a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Site Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="navigation-bar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="columns-area">
      <aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex sed pariatur corporis quo illo ad cum itaque, deserunt, fugiat repudiandae iure maxime sapiente id dolores? Ipsam soluta est sed aliquid.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Amet asperiores officia vitae saepe ullam, voluptates vero excepturi repudiandae. Maxime repudiandae mollitia perspiciatis explicabo eaque eum distinctio adipisci minus quod nesciunt.</aside>
    </section>
    <section class="footer">
      <p class="footer-text">Site created by <a href="#">Mattew</a>
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why? what would be the benefit of doing so? You could use percent widths, but eventually you're going to want those two columns to become one, which would require js intervention if not using media queries.

Comment: What do you have against flexbox and media queries?

Comment: _I would know if is possible create a site responsive to 100% without flexbox or media queries_ Is there a specific reason for that, or are you just enjoy this bizarre challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

> max-width: 100%